# Get params cookie_domain

Tags: 8

I would like to retrieve the parameter cookie_domain set in the services.yml like this:

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    cookie_domain: '.domain.ext'
```

I try this:

```
(new SessionConfiguration())->getOptions(\Drupal::request());
```

This recovers the default value not my value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the cookie domain this way using the session_configuration service.

```
$sessionConfig =\Drupal::service('session_configuration');
// Get the current request.
$request = \Drupal::request();
// Get options from the request.
$options = $sessionConfig->getOptions($request);
$cookie_domain = $options['cookie_domain'];
```

Comment: ! It is the same like my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this approach:

```
$session_parameters = Drupal::getContainer()->getParameter('session.storage.options');
$cookie_domain = $session_parameters['cookie_domain'];
```

example:

```
// Get the cookie domain from container parameter config
$cookie_domain = '';
try {
  $session_parameters = Drupal::getContainer()->getParameter('session.storage.options');
  $cookie_domain = $session_parameters['cookie_domain'];
} catch (Exception $e) {
  watchdog_exception('cookie_domain', $e);
}
```